# Google earth installation in Ubuntu 13.10 fail

Tags: 13.10, google-earth

I followed the instructions found in this site with no success. Here is the terminal window:

```
pierpaolo1942@ubuntuhome:~$ wget http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
--2013-10-28 15:36:10--  http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4003:c02::88, 74.125.227.226, 74.125.227.238, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4003:c02::88|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 45541972 (43M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb’

100%[=============================================================================================>] 45,541,972   657KB/s   in 77s    

2013-10-28 15:37:27 (575 KB/s) - ‘google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb’ saved [45541972/45541972]

pierpaolo1942@ubuntuhome:~$ sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable*.deb
[sudo] password for pierpaolo1942: 
Selecting previously unselected package google-earth-stable.
(Reading database ... 338485 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-earth-stable (from google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
Setting up google-earth-stable (7.1.1.1888-r0) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
pierpaolo1942@ubuntuhome:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  printer-driver-hpijs
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
pierpaolo1942@ubuntuhome:~$
```

Thank for your time.

Comment: Err... I don't see where it fails? It's already installed correctly.

Comment: Try running `google-earth`, or `ls /bin | grep google` to see if there are any commands available to execute via command line. It does look like it has installed correctly, it is just telling you 'printer-driver-hpijs' is not longer required, perhaps due to installing a replacement with google-earth. It _should_ be fine (I think).

Answer (score 0):

**Google Earth Build Package**

***This is a workaround***

Download Google Earth x64 .DEB

Open Terminal, Copy & Paste Following Command And Press Enter

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 lsb-core
```

Open Downloads Folder

Right Click On Google Earth .DEB Package & Select Extract Here

Click On Debian Folder

Right Click on Control & Select Open In Gedit

Remove The Whole Line Containing

**Depends: lsb-core (>= 3.2), ia32-libs**

Now Click Save, & Exit Control File

Now Delete The Original Google Earth .DEB Package You Downloaded

Create A Folder called getfix, Now Move The Extracted Google Earth Folder Into The getfix Folder

Now You Are Going To Rebuild The Google Earth .DEB Package

Open Terminal, Copy & Paste Following Command & Press Enter

```
dpkg -b /home/username/Downloads/getfix/google-earth-stable_current_amd64
```

Once You Have Done That, Back In Terminal Copy & Paste The Following Command

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/username/Downloads/getfix/google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

The Repackaged Google Earth Will Now Be Installed.